# Is there a straight way to copy or clone a QgsVectorLayer Object?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

Is there a straight way to clone or "deepcopy" a QgsVectorLayer Object with python? Unfortunately the python module "copy" is not successful with that.

Comment: In the QGIS 1.9 nightly build is a new function which allows to copy a layer from the layerbox via a simple mouseclick (rightclick on layer, copy). Maybe you can search for the respective function in the QGIS api

Comment: I have to solve it for Version 1.8. But otherwise this might work. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `QgsVectorLayer` class is just a view into the underlying data source so you can just do this to make a new layer:

```
newlayer = QgsVectorLayer(layer.source(), layer.name(), layer.providerType())
```

where `layer` is a instance of another `QgsVectorLayer`

Comment: They really should add a copy method...

Comment: Actually there is now https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeNode.html#a6ec9f401dfe34909830758ed8712a106

Comment: @Maccesch no that is cloning the legend item not the layer itself.